# php tool for generating css shorthand

Tags: php, css, shorthand

I'm generating a dynamic CSS using PHP. I've got individual values looking like:

```
$padding_top  = 10;
$padding_bottom = 10;
$padding_left  = 10;
$padding_right  = 10;
```

Now, I would like to generate CSS shorthand for all css rules where shorthand notation is possible. So the above example should turn into:

```
padding: 10px;
```

I'm sure there must already be a library for this, but I couldn't find it, and before I start writing a hairy heap of conditional statements, I thought I'd give it a go here first.. Any suggestions as to how to most elegantly achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** as per comments,

maybe worthwhile taking a look at [CSSTidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/) and building something on that

> CSSTidy is an opensource CSS parser
>   and optimiser. It is available as
>   executeable file (available for
>   Windows, Linux and OSX) which can be
>   controlled per command line and as PHP
>   script (both with almost the same
>   functionality). In opposite to most
>   other CSS parsers, no regular
>   expressions are used and thus CSSTidy
>   has full CSS2 support and a higher
>   reliability.

---

have you tried [LESSPHP](http://leafo.net/lessphp/)

not sure it'll do exactly what you're asking but you should be able to build your own mixins to suit

Comment: I've looked at LESSPHP but didn't find that it does what I'm looking for here, plus I'm looking for something lightweight that will only do the shorthand conversion. I'm using CSSEdit from MacRabbit for manual CSS coding, and notices how it intelligently constructs converts to shorthand whenever the values entered in the properties editor allow for a shorter representation.. And I was hoping to find a PHP lib that would be able to do something like that..

Comment: ah, I did think that and took a look but didn't find anything either. I don't think there will be something like that. Shorthand code is great but because it has the ability to override previous longhand declarations especially things like background, it's not always desirable. A tool which auto converts to shorthand might inadvertently change a page. It would need to understand the cascade and your intentions - so possibly best to write your own. You could use if/else logic to compare the values and output 1,2,3 or 4 values (as in 'padding/border' type rules) as required?

Comment: @mikkelbreum maybe build something based on [CSSTidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @clairesuzy do you want to post your link to CSSTidy as an answer.. then I'll accept it, it's an interesting option that I was not aware of, and there are no better answers yet.

Comment: @clairesuzy actually playing a little more with CSSTidy shows very promising results, it perfectly converts into shorthand, intelligently and with safety options. It fixes bad syntax, and does size optimization. Very good. And it's available as a PHP class. It's perfect, thanks.

Comment: You're Welcome, glad to have helped and you found it useful, have added the link and quote as update to my answer!